# JQuery Adding of row in table not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

I'm trying to add a row in a table from a data from another table. it says uncaught reference error.

here's the function

```
function addItem(id, name){
    bootbox.confirm("Are you sure?", function(result) {
        if (result) {
            $('#ingredients_table').append("<tr><td>"+name+"</td></tr>");
        }
    });
}
```

here's the table where I'm calling the js function

```
<?php foreach($inventory as $row): ?>
    <tr style="cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Add ingredient" onclick="javascript:addItem(<?php echo $row->inventory_id; ?>, <?php echo $row->name; ?>)">
    <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The ID is showing in the table when I switch them, but the name is not.

Comment: Show the rendered HTML results since that is what the function and jQuery work with.

Comment: since u are using php better enclose parameters in quotes like **onclick="javascript:addItem('<?php echo $row->inventory_id;?>','<?php echo $row->name;?>')"**

Comment: @VibinTV that solved the problem, seems that it needs quotes. Thanks man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

use `''` (quotes)  for javascript function arguments

```
 <?php foreach($inventory as $row): ?>
    <tr style="cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top"
        title="Add ingredient" 
        onclick="javascript:addItem('<?php echo $row->inventory_id; ?>', '<?php echo $row->name; ?>')">

   <td><?php echo $row->name; ?></td>
```

Comment: glad it helps you , happy coding

Comment: @Alvinrightback don't forget to accept answer if solved for you.